# Where does the "type" come from in $_FILES?

Tags: php, security, file

when you upload files, you can then get the necessary data from $_FILES
files contains the list of file inputs, where each one has a field like [type]

for example:

```
Array
(
    [file1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 'MyFile.txt'
            [type] => text/plain  //where does this come from?
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php/php1h4j1o
            [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
            [size] => 123
        )
)
```

does it come from within the file, or the file extension, or somewhere else?
how does php get the type?
where does the [type] come from and can I trust it as valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

```
$_FILES['userfile']['type']
```

> The mime type of the file, if the
>   browser provided this information. An
>   example would be "image/gif". This
>   mime type is however not checked on
>   the PHP side and therefore don't  take
>   its value for granted.

Answer (score 4):

The browser attempts to determine the MIME type from the file name, possibly from its extension, then sends this as part of the upload request. Thus, in your example, the file extension `.txt` would correspond to a MIME type of `text/plain`. This depends on the browser's implementation though.

Since not only does every browser have its own way of determining the MIME type, but the MIME type can also be intentionally spoofed simply by changing the file extension (among a plethora of other methods), it should not be trusted as always correct.

In fact, you're much better off trying to read the contents of the file or something to validate it.

Comment: @seengee: -clicks everyone's answer scores- Yeah, somehow! :O

Comment: @BoltClock I know this looks highly suspect on my behalf but honestly wasnt me!

Comment: @seengee: Don't worry, I trust you! Your reputation wouldn't still be ending in 5 if you were casting downvotes here ;)

Comment: @seengee - only to SO newcomers, others realize you couldn't have upvoted your own answer :)

Comment: @Nick Craver who says he couldn't :P (as someone else)

Answer (score 1):

The type is determined and set by the *browser*. That means it'll be influenced by browser make, version, installed programs and a plethora of other things. In other words, it's pretty much useless to the server-side application.

(For example, this means that photos uploaded by MSIE will have `type => image/pjpeg`; while the most common MIME type for JPEGs is `image/jpeg`)

Comment: AFAIK it's used for progressive (hence the P) JPEGs.

Comment: yeah, used for progressive jpegs and only sent for them

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Interesting, didn't know that.